# Using dav://host.local gives error message "Connection refused"

Tags: file-sharing, virtualbox-networking, webdav

Host is Ubuntu 18.4, gnome 3.28.2.

Using Virtualbox 5.2.10_Ubuntu r121806, the guest is running PureOS release 8 and gnome 3.25.92.  For this guest I am using a bridged adapter that allows VMs and is cable connected.

In the PureOS guest I enabled personal file sharing.  I did NOT require a password.  When I did that, it provided a message that to access the share I should use the URI dav://VBPOS.local.  However, when I open Nautilus on the host, and in the field for "Connect to Server" I enter that URI, I get this error message:  "Unable to access location / HTTP Error: Could not connect:  Connection refused".

I spent hours searching online to figure this out, I didn't find anything that was helpful.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Cheers!

Comment: @jmdev , sadly, no, I never found a resolution.  I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: I enabled file sharing in Gnome on host A and the shared folder from host A was automatically discovered by host B on the same network, but it was not possible to access its content due to a connection error. Such error usually means there is a firewall blocking the destination port and that turned out to be the case. However the port number was different from the expected HTTP/S ports (80/443). I ran `netstat -tpan` and found an instance of httpd listening on port 43995. After enabling this port on host A's firewall I was able to mount the share on host B and access its content.